# ¿Por qué date_format da un warning en un servidor y en otro no?

Tags: php

Tengo un script que viene desde un MySQL que lo simplifiqué para no poner el codigo completo. El caso es que en un servidor no funciona para nada y en el mío me da una advertencia (*warning*).

Aquí está el código:

```
$fecha = ("2016-02-12 12:06:07");
$fecha = date_format($fecha, 'Y-m-d');
```

Aquí el error:

> Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string
>   given in C:\Program Files (x86)\Vertrigo\www\scripts\data.php on line
>   14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Que en servidor te arroje el **Warning** y en otro no, tiene que ver con que estén activadas o desactivadas las notificaciones. Puedes probar incluyendo la siguiente línea al principio de tu código para desactivar las notificaciones:

```
<?PHP
    //Desactivar toda notificación de error
    error_reporting(0);
?>
```

Ahora, de todas maneras el formato correcto para lo que intentas sería el siguiente:

```
<?PHP
    $fecha = date_create('2016-02-12 12:06:07');
    $fecha_nueva =  date_format($fecha, 'Y-m-d');

    echo $fecha_nueva;

?>
```

Pruebalo y me cuentas 
Saludos!

Comment: Es verdad! ahora funciona en los dos servidores gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Saludo, la función `date_format()` es un alias de: `DateTime::format()`, funciona perfectamente en la versión 5 en adelante de PHP. Me fije en algo de tu codigo y tienes que poner otra regla mas y es para que reconozca Las horas, minutos y segundos **H:i:s**. Te dejo un ejemplo;

```
<?php
  $fecha=date_create("2016-02-12 12:06:07");
  echo date_format($fecha,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
?>
```

Comment: Quizás OP no quiere que se muestren las horas y minutos

Comment: Lo que pasa que en la base de datos viene con ese formato pero lo que necesito es mostrar la fecha si la horas, por eso solo lo dejo con  Y-m-d. Gracias.

Comment: Ok, igual funciona si no quieres mostrar las horas, espero haberte ayudado...